# How to get Data Factory logging information?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

Does Microsoft has any documentation. I need complete information to a run pipeline, i.e

Start time, end time, pipeline job id, no of record inserted, deleted, update, error, etc

Answer (score 1):

ADF doesn't currently write to the Azure Activity Logs, meaning you can't access details using the Azure Monitor.

Currently the best way I find to get this information is using PowerShell. For example:

```
Get-AzureRmDataFactoryActivityWindow `
    -DataFactoryName $ADFName.DataFactoryName `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
    | ? {$_.WindowStart -ge $Now} `
    | SELECT ActivityName, ActivityType, WindowState, RunStart, InputDatasets, OutputDatasets `
    | Sort-Object ActivityName
```

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactories/get-azurermdatafactoryactivitywindow?view=azurermps-4.0.0

Hope this helps

Comment: when I run this script in the Cloud shell (portal) facing this issue - "Get-AzureRmDataFactoryActivityWindow : The term 'Get-AzDataFactoryActivityWindow' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program." any suggestions on this

Comment: @ShashiKiran you probably need to install/update your Azure PowerShell module. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-1.8.0)

Comment: Looks like there's some capability there now? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python, you can use Azure Python SDK to access the pipeline_runs and activity_runs metadata and write to a database table.

Answer (score -1):

Currently, Microsoft allows you to pull all the pipeline execution information using the REST api : It's a simple GET Request :  [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelineruns/{runId}?api-version=2018-06-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/%7BfactoryName%7D/pipelineruns/%7BrunId%7D?api-version=2018-06-01)

Check out this link for more information on the API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelineruns/get