# Monitor ADF pipeline status using Power BI

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-factory

Is there any way we can fetch ADF pipeline metadata into Power BI. I want details like dataset names, slice start and end time and status.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a built-in dataset or functionality in the portal (ADF V2) but the way I do this is by using the Python SDK, I basically get the metadata of every activity run, not sure if you're using ADF V2 and if your are using Python  (there are similar functions for .NET)

More details in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.activityrun?view=azure-python)

```
 def _get_activity_metadata(self, pipeline_run_id, start_time, end_time, activity_name):

     act_runs = self.adf_client.activity_runs.list_by_pipeline_run(self.resource_group_name, self.data_factory_name,
                                                                  run_id=pipeline_run_id,
                                                                  start_time=start_time,
                                                                  end_time=end_time,
                                                                  activity_name=activity_name)
    for act in act_runs:
        act_run_id = act.activity_run_id
        act_status = act.status
        act_error = act.error
        act_run_end = act.activity_run_end
        act_run_end_est = act_run_end.astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))
        result = {'last_run_time': act_run_end_est,
                  'status': act_status,
                  'error': act.error,
                  'duration_in_ms': act.duration_in_ms,
                  'input': act.input,
                  'output': act.output
                  }

    return result
```

Then, I get the result and insert into a SQL Table/View and visualize in PowerBI, DOMO, SSRS, Excel, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the Data Factory v1, you should have a look at this [blog post](https://blog.gbrueckl.at/2017/01/monitoring-azure-data-factory-powerbi/). It explains how to use the REST API to get Data Factory run-data and import it to PowerBI. It even has a PowerBI template file to get you started. An alternative is using PowerShell as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259820/how-we-get-data-factory-logging-information)

For v2, at this moment I'm looking at the built-in logging. You can configure it  [with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor). I'm writing the logs to a Storage Account and import it with PowerBI, but it's also possible to monitor it with OMS for example.